# How to maintain position of rotation for cloned element when start rotating using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i cloned rotatable element,the previous rotation is comes to start point when i start rotation on cloned element.pls helps this

```
var newdiv = $(imageid).parent().clone();
                var id = "div" + divid;
                var imid = "img" + imgid;
                $(newdiv).attr('id', id);
                $(newdiv).find("img:first").attr("id", imid)
                $(newdiv).css("z-index", newZindex);

                $(newdiv).find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();
                var position = $(imageid).parent().position();
                $(newdiv).addClass("selected clone").css({ "top": position.top + 20, "left": position.left + 20 }).appendTo("#selectable"); 
               $("#" + id).rotatable({ handle: $(newdiv).find('img:last').addClass("rotatable-handle") }, {
                stop: stopHandlerRotate,
                start: startHandlerRotate
            }).resizable({
                handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"
            }, {
                stop: stopHandlerResize,
                start: startHandlerResize
            }).draggable({
                stop: stopHandlerDrag,
                start: startHandlerDrag
            });
```

when i cloned element its comes like this check image [cloned](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7NHkBYn66YGNE9nMWpObnB1MDA/view?usp=sharing).
when i click on start rotation it goes to start position. check image [clonedrotate](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7NHkBYn66YGV1ZCTG1tb2dFQ2c/view?usp=sharing)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here i am finding previous angle before rebind and gives it on binding.

```
$("#" + id).rotatable({ handle: $(newdiv).find('img:last').addClass("rotatable-handle") },{angle:previousangle}, {
                stop: stopHandlerRotate,
                start: startHandlerRotate
            }).resizable({
                handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"
            }, {
                stop: stopHandlerResize,
                start: startHandlerResize
            }).draggable({
                stop: stopHandlerDrag,
                start: startHandlerDrag
            });
```

Now its working.